# @ComponentScan does not exist in org.springframework.context.annotation package

Tags: java, spring

I am new spring framework, and i was practicing of java Configuration(No XML)

In this example I had need @Configuration and @ComponentScan(), which should be present in `org.springframework.context.annotation` package but in this package @Configuration is available but @ComponentScan is not.

Whenever i am trying to use @ComponentScan  eclipse suggests me to import @ComponentScan from `org.springframework.config.java.plugin.context` package which is not working properly.

When importing

> org.springframework.config.java.plugin.context.ComponentScan

I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'name' is defined
```

[image: NoXmlConfig.java]
[image: <code>org.springframework.context.annotation</code> package]

Comment: That means that you don't have the correct libraries in your dependancies. I am guessing you are using maven? Can you show your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: No i am not using maven i have just created simple java project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
I tried to improve the readability by editing the text.

Comment: Show us a complete example you tried to compile, and tell us precisely where you downloaded the jar file supposed to contain those classes.

Comment: @Geeky, can you paste some code for better understanding

Comment: yes @Mayur i have just added screenshot of NoXmlConfg.java and `org.springframework.context` jar

Comment: please do not post screenshot. Post code and read  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: spring 3.0.1 is completely obsolete, for years. Use the latest stable version. Spring framework is at version 5.1.5. Read the official user guides.

Comment: @JB Nizet i updated spring framework version 3.0.1 to 5.1.5 it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring version you are using 3.0.1 is old one in which @ComponentScan is not present. @ComponentScan is introduced in 3.1 you can check spring document [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

It is mentioned it is present since 3.1

[image]

Please try version 3.1 or higher.