# Not able to run a simple annotation based spring project

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning spring framework using annotations according to a tutorial, I keep getting these errors every time I run the code.
I have 3 files:

1)HelloWorld.java

```java
package com.test.app;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    
    HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");
    
    System.out.println(hw.getMsg());
  }
}
```

2)ApplicationConfig.java

```java
package com.test.app;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.test.app"})
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

3)Driver.java

```java
package com.test.app;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    
    HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");
  
    System.out.println(hw.getMsg());    
  }
}
```

I've added external jar files which were provided to me and they are:
[image: list of jar files]

The error I keep getting in eclipse:

```
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2286778: startup date [Tue Sep 07 19:02:35 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.test.app.ApplicationConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at com.test.app.Driver.main(Driver.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:166)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @61009542
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:46)
    ... 17 more
```

Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: The version of Spring jars (3.1.x) you're using looks very old. Maybe a problem of compatibility with new version of Java.

Comment: Still no luck, tried changing it to java 8 :(

Comment: Can you please correct `HelloWorld.java`? It has the same code as `Driver.java`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076659/componentscan-does-not-exist-in-org-springframework-context-annotation-package) the problem was that they used an old jar, which didn't include the @ComponentScan annotation.

Also you copied the Driver.java file under HelloWorld.java, please correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Merge `Driver.java` and `ApplicationConfig.java` as follows:

```java
package com.test.app;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationConfig {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    
    HelloWorld hw = (HelloWorld) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");
  
    System.out.println(hw.getMsg());    
  }
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Having said that, all your remaining classes must be in sub packages of `com.test.app`.